# Which GC option will be effected if I set 2 options both?

Tags: jboss, jvm

I am using jdk 1.7.0_80 and Jboss-eap-6.4.
Jboss is set with 2 GC options.
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC

This instance started normally. And I can find it "ps -ef" command, jcmd  VM.flags.
( order is +UseParallelGC , +UseParallelOldGC )

Which GC method will be used for this JVM ?
UseParallelGC or UseParallelOldGC  or Both ?

Checked jcmd , jinfo command.